# Querying a list in an untracked model causing the elements of the list to be tracked

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am getting an error that says

> Attaching an entity of type 'Application.Models.DatabaseModels.Bar' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

I've seen this error before and know that it is occurring because I am trying to set the state of an instance of `Bar` to modified, when the context is already tracking an instance that has the same id.  What is interesting to me is the situation that is causing `Bar`to be tracked before I try and set the state.

Below are two blocks of code that are identical in every way except for the addition of one line in the second block.  The first function will run correctly, changing the state of `foo.PrimaryBar` to modified, whereas the second function will throw the error.

**This Works Fine:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    Foo foo = await _context.Foos.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == viewModel.FooId);
    Foo.Primary.Bar = _context.Bars.AsNoTracking().First(c => c.Id == viewModel.PrimaryBarId);

    _context.SetModified(foo.Primary);

    //code continues
}
```

**This Throws An Error:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    Foo foo = await _context.Foos.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == viewModel.FooId);
    Foo.Primary.Bar = _context.Bars.AsNoTracking().First(c => c.Id == viewModel.PrimaryBarId);

    //this appears to add the Bars in Foo to the context
    var test = foo.Bars.Where(c => c.Id != foo.Primary.Bar.Id);

    //this is where the error occurs now
    _context.SetModified(foo.Primary);

    //code continues
}
```

To give context to the situation:

**Database Models**

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Primary")]
    public int? PrimaryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Primary Primary { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int? FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Primary
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Bar")]
    public int? BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public int? PrimaryBarId { get; set; }
}
```

**Context**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Foo>           Foos            { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Bar>           Bars            { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Primary>       PrimaryBars     { get; set; }


    public virtual void SetModified<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

**The Question**

Why does the line `var test = foo.Bars.Where(c => c.Id != foo.Primary.Bar.Id);` cause the `Bar`'s to be tracked by the context even though `foo` itself is set to `AsNoTracking()`?

Am I misunderstanding what is happening here, what `AsNoTracking()` does, or is this a bug in Entity Framework itself?

Comment: It seems that you have enabled the `Lazy Loading` which is delaying the loading of `Bars` data, until you specifically request for it. The data is in `Bars` must loaded by separate query of database (which you can validate in SQL profiler). However, your question is correct that why it is fetched with **Tracking** even if the parent is fetched with AsNoTracking. Otherway to confirm the behavior and may be workaround for your problem is to use `Eager Loading` of relationship data (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, using `_context.Foos.Include(f => f.Bars).etc` for `Eager Loading` seems to do nothing to fix the issue.  Interestingly enough, I discovered that the error actually disappears if I instead remove the `.AsNoTracking()` from my initial queries.  This _technically_ solves the issue I have - in that it removes the error - but I have no clue right now as to _why_ it works or even if it is doing what I actually want it to.